# What's the purpose of "mac-address 0000.0000.0000" in NX-OS?

Tags: cisco-nx-os

On a production Nexus 5K, I noticed the following piece of config:

```
interface Vlan1
  mac-address 0000.0000.0000
```

This is the entire Vlan1 stanza. What does this accomplish?

Comment: Are you the only technician that has access to this switch?  I'm wondering if someone manually put this in there.  If that is a possibility, I may be able to give you additional insight.

Comment: @Fizzle  That is the case -- there are other people with access, and I suspect this was manually put in to address ... something.  Initially I discovered this as I was auditing configs and sync between 5Ks.

Comment: Is there a Cisco ACE on the subnet? How about a Layer 3 card? We ran into an issue on a Nexus 7k where there was strange interaction between vPC, ACE and pinging SVIs that required statically setting the SVI MAC Address

Comment: No ACE on the subnet, so unfortunately can't be that bug.  Thanks.

Comment: It could be an attempt to disable vlan 1 by someone who mistakenly thought that was a good thing to do on a cisco switch.

Comment: It could be a rubbish "security through obscurity" technique, trying to force the SVI to have a MAC address of all zeros which is invalid so no one can communicate with the VLAN 1 instance. I'm not well exerpainced with Nexus switches, do they have a vlan 1 interface that can't be deleted like traditional IOS switches?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sadly,no

Answer (score 2):

Might be related to this known bug?

https://tools.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCua02927